# Show tiles while initializing map

Tags: android, skmaps

I am just learning to use the Skobbler SDK. The app "GPS Navigation & MAps Scout" by Telenav is showing tiles while the map is loading.

I am displaying the map in my app by using the SKMapViewHolder:

http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/android

But while the map is loading I've got a black screen. That doesn't look satisfying. I am using two Activities. The MainActivity initializes the library and the map. After initializing the map in `onMapTexturesPrepared()` I start an Intent which calls the MapActivity. There `onSurfaceCreated()` is called as soon as the map surface is created. But til the surface is created I would like to display tiles as it is done in the "GPS Navigation & MAps Scout" app. How to do that?

Regards
unlimited101

Comment: It could be connected with the multiple map implementation & GL context.  A fix that works in most scenarios is setting preserveGLContext to false when initializing the SDK: http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/android#sec029

Comment: Yeah, I just downloaded the demo frpm Skobbler SDK and looked up how they do it. It's pretty simple. The just place a relative layout with tiles as background. And they make it unvisible when `onSurfaceCreated()` is called.